# How to keep count of how many times a page is loaded

Tags: flutter

I want to clear the form fields that remain filled if I click the back button to go back to that forms screen. Thus, basically i want to call a function that will ALWAYS be executed once a page is navigated to so that i can call the controller.clear() function. Thanku.

Comment: so you want the inputs to reset themselves if the user navigates back from the form screen?

Comment: Ya that's what i want

Comment: thats the default behaviour , if a page id unmounted , the state will be deleted

Answer (score 1):

Can you call `controller.clear()` right before you navigate to a new screen from the forms screen. This way when they navigate back it will already be cleared.

Comment: Thanks bro, that is a very nice work around. But i want to know how to call a function everytime u navigate to a page. Because it's needed in many other senarios too.

Comment: Is the ```InitState()``` answer below mine not what you where looking for it seems like that would be what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a function when a page is loaded for the first time. the initState of the state class is the place you wann do your calls. because the initState is the first method that gets called when a widget gets mounted on the screen, even before the first render.

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();

  // call the functions you want to call

}
```

Comment: Ya i knew that already, but i want to call a function everytime the page is navigated to